# Wordpress widgets in my theme

Tags: wordpress, widget

I am new here as well as in web development :)
I have a question about wordpress.
I try to make sidebar-widgets.

In my sidebar.php file I write:

```
<div id="sidebar">

<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar() ) : ?>

<div>some html here </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

and in function.php

```
<?php
if ( function_exists('register_sidebars') )
    register_sidebar();
?>
```

But it does not appear in widgets list, but when I click appearance-widget, in right part it appears Sidebar 1, and I can't even move it.

Can you please help me how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your `functions.php`

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ){
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar_widget_1',
        'description' => 'Widgets in this area will be shown in the sidebar.',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="%2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>'
    )
);
```

In your `sidebar.php`

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar') ) : ?>
        <div>some html here </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks you.
But I still cannot drag and drop it. Neither I can do it with wordpress own widgets. Maybe I must somehow activate it in my template?

Comment: You can add WordPress widgets by drag and drop in the sidebar area, expand it if it's collapsed by clicking on right corner of the title bar.